# Simple text cleaning into all columns of a dataframe frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which I would like to implement some basic formation rules.

The dataframe is:

```
df <- structure(list(colname1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"TEXTA"), class = "factor"), colname2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L
), .Label = c("TEXTA", "TEXTB", "TEXTE"), class = "factor"), 
    colname3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "TEXTC", 
    "TEXTD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("colname1", "colname2", 
"colname3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I try to run the following for the whole dataframe data:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(tolower(df))
df2 <- as.data.frame(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df2))
```

but this converts the column names of dataframe to rows. What can I do to make in lower case and remove punctuation from all rows of the example dataframe (I am not interesting for colnames)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We remove the punctuation characters on  each column by looping through the columns (`lapply(df, ..`), assign the output back to the original dataset

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", tolower(x)))
```

---

Using `tidyverse`, this can be done by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", tolower(.))))
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can loop so easily between columns. thanks!